# Select Query - WebSQL

Tags: html, web-sql, select-query

I've the following code to select a row.. When I call the function with getRecords("Peter Sam"); one record is shown.. However if I just pass getRecords("Peter"); it says "No results".

```
  getRecords = function(cname){
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE (cname LIKE ?)', [cname], renderResults);
        });
    }
```

What is the correct usage of "LIKE" in "Select" query?? BTW where do I refer SQL syntax for WebSQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In transact SQL you would use a % as a wild card.
something like:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE cname LIKE ?%
```

However, WebSQL has been discontinued so I don't suggest using this method.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The following query worked for me,

SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE (cname LIKE ?);', ["%"+cname+"%"], renderResults

Also do you suggest me to use indexedDB instead of WebSQL?? If so, is indexedDB is supported in Android 2.3??

Answer (score 3):

```
getRecords = function(cname){
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE (cname LIKE ?)', ['%'+cname+'%'], renderResults);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string concatenation:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE cname LIKE '%' || ? || '%'
```